On a glassed landmass, how long would it take for plants to grow?
My story takes place 60 years after a roughly 250 mile diameter area of a landmass was glassed. Cities were melted, and all living things were incinerated in the blast, down to roughly 20 feet below the surface of the soil, and all rivers in the area were vaporized and underwent the same melting as the rest of the soil. The area was then twisted to resemble spikes, think similar looking to ferrofluid, then flash frozen to hold the shape. (all of this was done using programmed magic. the magic isn't relevant to the question except to explain how this happened and to say that there is no solution to biosphere collapse using this magic) This volcanic rock wouldn't have nearly as many nutrients as volcanic rock in the real world, since it's just melted topsoil and bedrock. Granted, it would have an incredibly high iron content in the areas that were once cities, and would have the nutrients from the ash of the creatures and people that once lived there.
The climate was a mix of grasslands and savanna before the glassing, though there would be a lot more flooding given that the water isn't absorbed by the volcanic rock. Volcanoes don't exist on the planet, since it is completely artificially made and isn't tectonically active, with the magnetosphere artificially created and maintained, so there wouldn't be any environmental precedent for something like this, i.e. no plants are adapted to grow in this sort of situation.
Given all of this, in the best possible circumstances, how much could the biosphere have recovered in the 60 years which followed?

See also https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/94269/40408

Molten rock does not normally become glass. The overwhelming majority of volcanic rocks are not glass.

@AlexP That's where the flash freeze is important, molten rock given time to cool will indeed form crystals rather than remaining amorphous, but if you cool it rapidly crystallisation is impossible and you get massive glass deposits.

As a note you need a rock cycle, or at least something that will fake it, or the planet will become sterile as water soluble nutrients all get leeched from the rocks and soil and deposited into the sea.

@Ash The rock cycle thing is solved by the planet being artificially maintained using the same sort of magic that keeps up the magnetosphere. it keeps soil decently fertile, and preserves larger structures like continents and mountains.

@AttleTheKobold That's cool just something I always like to make sure people have considered in building "static" worlds.

It depends. Useful plants: Decades or more likely centuries. Weeds: five minutes...!

actually you don't get a solid mass of glass, the thermal shock combined with uneven stresswill casue it to shatter in chunks almost instantly.

sure there is president for this, its called a forest fire, pioneer species will exist.

@John Except this is done by "programmed magic" physical norms can be safely ignored. But yes in the real world chilling molten glass like that would result in ~49087 square miles of splinters rather than any intact object.

@ash it doesn't matter how its cooled, as soon as the magic goes away it shatters, even if the magic somhow evened out all stresses, the first time the sun rises it will shatter.

@John Depends on the climate, properly annealed glass is tougher than most people give it credit for, and it this case we're probably dealing with tempered glass due to the fact that it is flash chilled, when it breaks it will disintegrate but it's going to take a lot more punishment than you think, especially because it's so thick. In a mild climate thermal tresses will be minimal.

@Ash, no they won't the size s important, the thermal stress over those distances is enough to buckle steel  and rip concrete apart, making it thick makes it worse becasue its thick and uneven diffrent parts shed heat at diffrent speeds.  And no this is not annealed glass, that requires extrememly slow cooling and for best results thermal cycling. flash cooling makes tempered glass. this is a prince ruperts drop but almost every part is the tail because it has been foamed by volitiles. this mass will be desperate to shatter, one break and it disintegrates.

There are two things here:

The glass itself is going to be extremely rich in a number of elements that don't usually occur at high levels in volcanic rocks, it's also likely to be highly porous. This is because soil, and continental rock for that matter, contains a lot of Carbon and light(er) reactive elements when compared to something like basalt. Much of the glass field may resemble carbonatites in terms of reactivity and dissolve quite readily under normal rainfall. The relatively very high level of aluminium in the melt will also be particularly telling, as will industrial metals like copper and zinc from the destroyed cities. The high level of volitiles incorporated in the melt is going to mean the glass is also full of air pockets making it physically fragile as well.

There is also an edge, that is going to be subject to erosion. Where the topography outside the edge is higher than the glass zone water and soil are going to run onto/across the glass surface. This directly erodes the surface of the material and also allows plant growth to start. Many pioneer species are nitrogen fixers that produce strong acids at their roots (to the point of lowering soil pH to 2 or less during periods of soil saturation) that will accelerate glass degradation. Where the glass is higher than the unaffected land water will run off and erode the land beyond the edge undercutting the glass slab, glass has poor tensile strength so chunks are going to break off quite quickly once unsupported.


Between these factors the glassed zone will be relatively fragile and erosion along the edges will be quite rapid. Now 60 years is not terribly long on the normal scale of geological processes but depending on the exact chemistry of a given patch of glass it could already be gone after the first decent downpour.
End result; I'd expect the zone to be very patchy after 60 years and several miles to several tens of miles smaller in total radius as the edges get broken up by vegetation, water, and soil motion.
I had been thinking about a mild climate setting, until @AcePL made a good point, if this happens in an area that experiences deep ground frosts then between frost heave and frost wedging porous glassy material is going to fairly disintegrate over a few cycles. Even in climates that don't get frosts but do get a lot of strong sunlight during the day the thermal stress weathering, particularly thermo-mechanic fatigue, could do a lot of damage. After a decade or so you'd have to dig up relatively solid glass nuggets to know what had happened, those more solid pockets of glass will exist but they're unlikely to be particularly large.

Also, depending on the geographical location, then temperature changes would make that process even quicker. In some areas with dense population levels,  soil freezes more than 1 meter of depth during winter. This repeated freeze/thaw cycle can, in theory, reduce the more resilient parts of the glass layer to the area littered with small to medium pieces of the glass, with vegetation intruding, in probably less than a decade, into more or less whole 250 mile radius.

with that many volitiles you will get something more like scoria or ither highly porous volcanic, just consider how much trapped water there is during the heat. that will make it weak meaning the uneven thermal stress will break it into chunks almost instantly just like real laval feilds. if you foam molten rock then cool it, it rips itself apart.

@John Except created and frozen in place by magic otherwise yes it would basically explode at formation.

@AcePL Yeah I'd thought about this being next door, we don't have regular frosts around here (even in the very middle of winter we're lucky to get three surface frosts in a week, no deep freezes), and hadn't considered true freeze-thaw cycles. Given the porous surfaces involved the first good freeze is going to break chunks off everywhere. Above the frost line and after five years you'll be lucky to find anything much bigger than a golf ball.

@Ash it doesn't matter, the first uneven heating from a day/night cycle will shatter it almost as completely.

I would add that since a glassed area would have poor water circulation, within a few months it will have countless small puddles, ponds, or even lakes of rainwater trapped ontop of glass layers. This means that water-dwelling bacteria, insects and small vertebrates will have a perfect environment all of the sudden.

@GoingDurden True, that's worth expanding into a full answer.

Speaking form a purely biological perspective, the answer is "as soon as it's cool enough not to kill anything organic that touches it". In fact, it will start growing basic life such as bacteria the first time that it rains, and everything afterwards will follow.
Bacteria, mold and algae - along with the nutrients that they need - will arrive in the first rain that falls, and will start to form on the surface within days of that, especially in the pools and gullies between the spires\spikes. The surface will start to look dulled and grubby as organisms begin to expand into a niche with no natural competition. They will feed on the nutrients carried in by the rain, and will create a bio-film on which more complicated organisms can live. Which in turn will start to attract animals, that will carry yet more complex organisms with them, including seeds in their droppings.
As the other answers said, dust and debris will be blown in by the wind and will accumulate in nooks and crannies, and hollows, insects will lay their eggs in shaded pools and animals that feed off of them will come, brining vegetation with them in the form of seeds on their coasts\feathers or in their droppings.
Unless the region has a particularly harsh environment you will see substantial greening the following spring.
So, it would go from glass to sparse grassland in the space of one growing season.

This reads like Bacteria, mold and algae are born by pure magic. On RL Earth, they would be airborne, then rainborne.

@François Jurain, The bacteria and algae are in the rain, this happens in real life.

I like this answer - but I am curious - would this still apply if the composition of rocks formed acidic compounds in the rain - e.g. a high sulfur content making a form of sulfuric acid.

@AarghZombies there is a good paper on this here: https://www.nature.com/articles/s43247-024-01280-3. It is about volcanic ash/flow colonization by prokeryotes etc... But thats similar enough (sterilized habitat) to the glassed landmass to provide a fair comparision.

@TheDemonLord, we see this with both extreme acid and extreme alkali around hot springs.

@AaarghZombies - So, I live in NZ and have visited Rotorua multiple times - there is definitely a dead zone around some of the hot pools - which is why I was thinking about this.

Since it's only a limited area to be glassed, all the glass will be accumulating dust and debris carried by weather from all around it.
This means that it won't take long for lichens to start growing, followed by grass, shrubs and small plants the more dust and debris will accumulate. Once vegetation is there, also animal can follow.
At the same time the more exposed part will be sanded by wind carried particles.
My estimate is that in 60 years you might even start to have trees and not notice much differences with the unglassed surrounding regions.

but how would the plants grow? there's ~20 feet of solid volcanic rock with effectively 0 water absorbance. unless this rock is almost entirely gone in 60 years, it would make it incredibly difficult for any larger plants to grow. also a small point of clarification, "glassed" does not mean literal glass, it's a term that comes from the idea of melting an entire area until nothing but volcanic glass remains

@AttleTheKobold on my tar covered roof, if I don't clean away the debris, plants start growing just after one year. It will be the debris itself to hold some water.

in this situation there isn't really any debris to hold the seeds or water. what exactly is the texture of a tar roof? is it comparable to solid rock?

@AttleTheKobold please read what I have written: debris will be carried by wind and precipitation, because the surrounding area will keep producing it.

Right, i misunderstood what you meant by debris. though there is still the problem, any sort of large plant still has 20 feet of rock below it, so trees and bushes can't grow without something to support their root structure, and leaves and debris can't do that on their own.

@AttleTheKobold don't underestimate neither the accumulation rate of debris nor the ability of plants (tree included) to grow in seemly harsh conditions.

@AttleTheKobold On that subject the New Zealand Pohutukawa tree is almost impossible to make into bonsai due to it's ability to grow to full size in as little as half a teaspoon of soil, I've seen a successful Pohutukawa bonsai, it was growing wired to a glazed plate with a little gravel built up to protect the roots from light damage, no organic soil except what it had shed since the last maintenance session, the guy said he used a nutrient spray once a week.

Two points: 1) some trees and bushes root very shallowly in all circumstances, and 2) even ones that want deep roots will TRY to grow on your glassed surface, and while they won't achieve full size they will assist in wedging cracks, breaking the surface, and depositing more topsoil.

@AttleTheKobold, mosses will start to grow within the year on anything they can attach to. There's very little difference between concrete, granite or a glassed world. As long as you haven't somehow actually wiped out the mosses and lichens they will start to form very quickly once the surface has cooled. They're the first colonisers on any fresh volcanic surface and they'll be the first on your world as well.

I would argue the Glass-land would become a richer environment than the grass-land, because class layer will capture water better. It would be a land of ponds, marshes and even small lakes within years, and that would attract far more life than a dry savannah.

There is an actual close equivalent of this that occurred after the May 18, 1980 explosion of Mount Saint Helens, when large areas of forest were essentially cooked at high temperature (and all trees were physically knocked down by the force of the blast), and all visible life was killed. The entire area became a grey, sterile wasteland.
Several studies have been done of the recovery of nature after this event: you might find it instructive to track down some of these records.
Notably, some plants were beginning to grow again within a year or two after the event (apparently a few seeds survived, perhaps because they were buried under ash and insulated by it from the high temperatures, or perhaps because visiting birds pooped them out), and creatures such as deer, mice, etc. were starting to venture into the area soon after. Within a decade or two, large amounts of the forest have mostly recovered. (Obviously there are still a lot of fallen, dead trees.)

The grey surface left by the St Helens eruptions was a relatively thin coating of nutrient rich volcanic ash the OP is asking about an impermeable layer 6m or more thick.

@Ash In many places the layer of ash was 12 feet deep or more. I have witnessed this personally, touring the site within 6 months after the damage. The explosion and its aftereffects deposited over a half inch of ash in my driveway, 80 miles away, and I was to the south of the mountain (the explosion blew north).

Also, the ash may have been "nutrient rich" once various bacteria, fungi, etc. had time to start attacking it chemically over a few years, but in its original form as the mountain deposited it everywhere, about the closest equivalent I can compare it to would be gray powdered glass. Sterile, with no form of life in it, and with sharp corners. Not something you want to breathe without a mask, or even something you want to let your car windshield wipers wipe off of your car (it would tear up your windshield). Nasty stuff.

Yes but most of it went down the river in the first rainfall, terrible for the fish, meant the soil was exposed and regeneration began almost immediately.

@Ash, a layer of glass would be fantastic at capturing rainwater and moisture, thus creatign countless ponds,  pools and even shallow lakes, which would fill with life far faster than soil could. Unless the water was toxic from the ash, there would be algae and mosquito larvae in it within days.

@GoingDurden Yes but this OP is equating a thin layer of volcanic ash to that glass layer which is not a useful comparison.

The claim that 12 feet or more of ash "went down the river in the first rainfall" is simply not even close to accurate. Most of the deposited ash was not immediately adjacent to a stream or river. It compacts, settles, and solidifies when wet, just like dust or sand, and hence is no more likely to get washed away. I was in that region a few months ago (north side of Mt. St. Helens, close to the mountain and inside the blast zone), and large regions of ash were still visible on the flat plains surrounding the mountain. Much of the ash has even been stabilized by plant growth at this point.

You can look at this video to see the huge piles of ash and rocks that were thrown out of the mountain onto nearby areas and still exist in the area to this day. Much of it has been covered by a thin layer of plant life at this point, but that doesn't change the fact that what spewed out of the mountain was far more than "a thin layer of ash". It was a MASSIVE landslide of stone (the entire side of the mountain!), followed by an explosion of superheated supersonic boulders, rocks, gravel, ash, etc. of various sizes and compositions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOFKwCELHw8

Comparisons:
Look at the speed that wide spread volcanic flows get green again. You want to compare to shield volcanoes where the lava is fairly runny.
Western washington and southern Idaho experieced MASSIVE lava floods -- some 2500 feet of basalt over the course of about 20,000 years.  It was episodic.  But look at erosion in Washingtion you can see layers 50 feet thick.
Rock and glass are both weak in tension on a large scale.  Unless prevented by ongoing magic, the glass will crack with changes in temperature.  These cracks allow water, dust to collect.  I would expect to see most of it being at least sparsely green (like a desert) within 100 years.  I'd expect the edge to start showing green in a very few years.

Expanding from a comment:
The Glass-land would prevent water circulation, since, even when cracked, glass is watertight.
Within months the glassed lands would be filled with ponds, puddles and marshes made of rainwater, and any river that intersected with the glassed area would either spread onto it, or be dammed by it, forming some extra marshland.
You basically created a shallow, cracked aquarium.
Waterborne life would psread quickly: algae, mosquito larvae, then small plants etc. In 60 years, it would look like a mangrove forest or swampland, with odd bits of glass occasionally visible here and there.
If anything, it will become a richer environment than the savanna around it.
